# Java, How to convert a string into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, transform

I've got a string, for example:

```
String code = new String("[199, 56, 120]")
```

My goal is to create and Array that contains only the numbers inside the `[]` and beetween commas;
In this case it would be for example:

```
array[0] = 199  
array[1] = 56
array[2] = 120
```

Is possible to do something like this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function.

Skip the `[` and the `]` and you can do something like this:

```
String input = "199 56 120";
String[] array = input.split(" ");
```

If you really want `[` and the `]` then you can use something like

```
input.replace("[", "");
input.replace("]", "");
```

To strip the string before you split it.

**Edit**

It doesn't matter what the format is or what the numbers are or how many they are, you simply edit the split definition according to the format, so if you're case is `,` then you simply use that as the split parameter.

```
String input = "[number, number, number]";
String sep = ", ";
String fixedInput = input.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
String[] array = fixedInput.split(sep);
// array[0] contains first number.
// array[1] contains second number.
```

If you want an int[] array then you could do something like this:

```
int[] intArray = new int[array.length];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the String is random and has every time this format : [ number, number, number ] (the number can be from 0 to 200)

Comment: Look at my edit, can you be more precise? IT doesn't matter what the number is or how many they are.

Comment: This would be perfect. But the array should be an int array instead of a string array.. how can fix it??

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-line solution:

```
String[] array = code.replaceAll("[^\\d ]", "").split(" ");
```

The in-line call to `replaceAll()` removes non-digits/spaces.